# How to set Aptana to be my default BUNDLER_EDITOR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, editor, aptana

I try to open a gem using the following command:

```
$bundle open jquery-rails
```

but it gives me the following error:

```
To open a bundled gem, set $EDITOR or $BUNDLER_EDITOR
```

So,I have search a little bit at read that I should open my .bashrc file and set the BUNDLER_EDITOR variable. I did the following things:

```
sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
```

and at end of the file entered the line above:

```
export BUNDLER_EDITOR=aptana
```

In the example they are using vim but since I am using aptana studio 3 I want to use it.

Anyway, it give me the following error:

> Could not run 'aptana
>   /home/gotqn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/jquery-rails-2.1.3'

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried this but it dint work either:

```
export EDITOR="/Applications/Sublime.app" peterandersson@Macintosh:myapp(0)$ bundle open jquery-rails Could not run '/Applications/Sublime.app /Users/peterandersson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/jquery-rails-3.0.1'
```

and `export EDITOR=vimworks` however, but I'd rather use Sublime than vim:

This link describes how to set [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html) as the default `$EDITOR`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to set `$EDITOR` or `$BUNDLER_EDITOR` in `.profile` file.

You can set it like this:

```
export BUNDLER_EDITOR=aptana
```

Hope this works for you!

Comment: +1 For the answer, but I am not able to confirm it is a valid one as I give up the Aptana stuff and started using RubyMine. Anyway, thanks :- ]

Comment: Tried this but it didnt work either:`export EDITOR="/Applications/Sublime.app"`
`peterandersson@Macintosh:myapp(0)$ bundle open jquery-rails`
`Could not run '/Applications/Sublime.app /Users/peterandersson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/jquery-rails-3.0.1'`

Comment: This link describes how to set Sublime as the default $EDITOR: [OS X Command Line](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html)

Comment: @PeterAndersson Add this as separate answer please.